# How to use on Laravel guard for the main domain and another for the subdomains

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, multi-tenant, laravel-session

I'm building a multi-tenant application where the idea is the admins access through the main domain (http://myapp.app) to the dashboard and the regular users access to another dashboard on their respective subdomains (http://tenant-a.myapp.app).

To achieve this I created a custom guard(admin) that uses the **session driver** and the **admins provider** which is a custom provider that uses the **eloquent driver** and my table **admins**.

```
// config/auth.php

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

   'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
   ],

   'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
   ]
],


'providers' => [
   'users' => [
       'driver' => 'eloquent',
       'model' => Monica\Models\User::class,
    ],

   'admins' => [
       'driver' => 'eloquent',
       'model' => Monica\Models\Admin::class,
   ],
],
```

After reading a lot of documentation about how the authentication works I got the admins dashboard working event with the reset password system but the part of the subdomains still present some issues.

The login for the regular users on the tenant subdomain seems to be working since I got my user logged and if I check the remember option this is reflected on the database getting a token.

The most important issue that have is when I try to retrieve the user using the authentication functions (facade or injected) I can't get the user, the method always return me null.

I've tried to specify the guard to the auth object but still not work.

When I use the **guard object** it has a member **user** that it suppose to contain the logged user but it is always null and if you are about to ask me why I need the user it's because I need to check the permissions of the user.

My theories are that my session only works with the main domain and not with the subdomians or I need to specify another cookie but honestly I'm just guessing.

I don't even know what part of my code will be useful to post but if you are related with this problem, every light that you can give me is welcome, let me know if you need more information or an specific piece of my code.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

This is an extract of the `UserController.php`

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager as Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate;
use Monica\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;

    protected $gate;

    public function __construct(Auth $auth, Gate $gate)
    {
        $this->middleware('web');
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->gate = $gate;
        $this->auth->guard('web');
        $this->auth->shouldUse('web');
        $u = $this->auth->guard();
        dd($u);
    }
}
```

And this is the guard object dumped:

```
SessionGuard {#311 ▼
  #name: "admin"
  #lastAttempted: null
  #viaRemember: false
  #session: Store {#294 ▼
    #id: "XIWy7hEJRuX1cL2bBN7pf7DqT54PpbTyYBXPv6He"
    #name: "no_named_app_session"
    #attributes: array:5 [▼
       "_token" => "RrTXOZwj56Nk9OqxkdkLdDztfZb6TeW2knVf5xc7"
       "_previous" => array:1 [▼
       "url" => "http://monica.app/admin/admins"
    ]
      "_flash" => array:2 [▼
        "old" => []
        "new" => []
    ]
      "url" => []
      "login_admin_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => "66f4aab0-6566-11e8-b51d-673dcbafed23"
]
  #handler: FileSessionHandler {#295 ▼
    #files: Filesystem {#115}
    #path: "/home/vagrant/Code/PHP/monica/storage/framework/sessions"
    #minutes: "120"
  }
  #started: true
}
  #cookie: CookieJar {#292 ▼
    #path: "/"
    #domain: null
    #secure: false
    #sameSite: null
    #queued: []
  }
  #request: Request {#42 ▶}
  #events: Dispatcher {#26 ▶}
  #loggedOut: false
  #recallAttempted: false
  #user: Admin {#328 ▶}
  #provider: EloquentUserProvider {#308 ▼
    #hasher: BcryptHasher {#310 ▶}
    #model: "Monica\Models\Admin"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewed the life cycle of the Laravel Request I found that the user is not available inside of the **Auth** or **Guard** objects when the constructor of the Controller classes is being executed 
If you try to access to the logged user on the controller constructor

```
public function __construct(Auth $auth, Gate $gate)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->gate = $gate;
    $this->middleware('auth:web');
    $this->auth->shouldUse('web');
    $user = $this->auth->user()  // null
}
```

But if you access to the user in on the the controller methods, the user is going to be returned

```
public function index($subdomain)
{
    $user = $this->auth->user()->toArray();
}
```

This is user var dumped

```
array:6 [▼
    "id" => "670732c0-6566-11e8-93c6-41f6face77c8"
    "tenant_id" => "66f815e0-6566-11e8-83b2-37a662a96205"
    "name" => "user"
    "email" => "user@aetech.com"
    "created_at" => "2018-06-01 06:38:32"
    "updated_at" => "2018-06-01 06:38:32"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple different approaches to set the guard dynamically.

**1. Using `auth()->shouldUse('the_guard')`**

In a middleware or a controller's constructor, pass the name of the guard into the `shouldUse` method depending on the domain or hostname:

```
if (request()->getHttpHost() === 'myapp.com') {
    auth()->shouldUse('admin');
} else {
    auth()->shouldUse('api'); // use the guard for tenants
}
```

**2. Override the default config in `config/auth.php`, again, in a middleware or controller constructor:**

```
if (request()->getHttpHost() === 'myapp.com') {
    config(['auth.defaults.guard' => 'admin');
} else {
    config(['auth.defaults.guard' => 'api'); // use the guard for tenants
}
```

If you're using custom logic to login, be sure that the `Authenticable` model is set using one of the `auth` methods: login, once, attempt, etc.

I use the first method, `shouldUse`, across projects with an abstract base controller class which all other applicable controllers inherit from. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried setting the name of the guard but the user remains empty, I'm not sure if there a problem with the cookies or the sessions
I update the question with more information, maybe it helps